# Scanf throws a random exception when I try to use it(same for scanf_s)

Tags: c++, variables, char, scanf, visual-studio-2019

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char name[15];
    printf_s("What is your name: ");
    scanf_s("%s",name);
    printf_s("Nice to meet you, %s", name);
    return(0);
}
```

Please help idk whats wrong. Im doing this in VS2019 and using c++ if that helps.

Comment: Doesn't scanf_s require the size as the third parameter?

Comment: you arent really using any c++, afaik `scanf_s` / `printf_s` is not standard c++

Comment: What really would help is if you would give us a precise error message/problem description. You probably mean compiler error, not exception. Exceptions happen at runtime, unless your ide crashed while compiling ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use scanf instead of scanf_s, to silence the error you can write "#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS" on top of your code. Difference between scanf and scanf_s is, in scanf_s you can specify buffer size and control the size of an input to avoid crash. It's not necessary in this level but i suggest you to look into it.

Also, if you're using C++, you can declare strings like:

std::string varName, and cout/cin operations are way easier imo.

```
 #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char name[128];
    printf("What is your name: ");
    scanf("%s", &name);
    printf("Nice to meet you, %s", name);
    return(0);
}
```

Or in easier way:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::string name;
    std::cout<< "What is your name: ";
    std::cin >> name;
   std::cout << "Nice to meet you, " << name;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` is a Microsoft thing, not a C thing.